# Warum nennt man auf Deutsch die Zahlen 0, 2, 4 ... "gerade" Zahlen?

Tags: etymology, numbers, mathematics

Auf Deutsch werden ganze Zahlen, die ohne Rest durch 2 teilbar sind – also die Reihe

```
... -4, -2, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10 ...
```

– als *gerade* und die Zahlen

```
... -3, -1, 1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11 ...
```

als *ungerade* bezeichnet.

Warum?

Comment: Irgendwie bezweifele ich, dass man -4 und 0 als gerade Zahlen bezeichnet hat, oder zumindest ist das gerade sein bei diesen nicht der Rede wert. Im ursprünglichen Sinne dürfte sich das auf natürliche, also positive, ganze Zahlen bezogen haben.

Comment: Was hat das mit deutsch zu tun? Ist doch in anderen Sprachen auch so – z.B. im englischen (even/odd). Wäre m.M. nach schon wieder eine gute Frage für http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: @feela heißt "even" wörtlich "gerade"? Ja, aber nur bei Zahlen - und da beißt sich die Katze in den Schwanz. Außerdem: in anderen Sprachen, z. B. Italienisch: "numeri pari e dispari".

Comment: Mir ist dabei aufgefallen, dass viele Sprachen ungerade durch Negation von *gerade* bilden, nur im Englischen kennen ich den eigenen Begriff *odd*. Die Frage dazu wollte ich eigentlich schon länger stellen, jetzt hab ich sie auf http://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/764/which-languages-have-there-own-word-for-odd-and-which-languages-use-a-negation gestellt.

Comment: "Gerade" und "krumm" sind Gegensätze. Eine "krumme" Zahl ist eine Zahl, die schlecht teilbar ist, oft eine Zahl mit Nachkommastellen (obwohl ich schon gelesen habe, dass 42 nicht nur eine relevante Antwort sei, sondern auch eine krumme Zahl). Ich kann mir daher gut vorstellen, dass die Beschreibung einer Zahl, die sich ohne Rest durch 2 teilen lässt, als "gerade" einen ähnlichen Ursprung hat wie die Beschreibung einer schlecht teilbaren Zahl als "krumm". Auch wenn man in der Mathematik das Adjektiv "gerade" mittlerweile(?!) als Gegensatz zu "ungerade" versteht.

Comment: @bernd_k Also in meinem Mathestudium hat man auch die negativen durch zwei teilbaren Zahlen als gerade bezeichnet. Warum auch nicht? Natürlich kann es sein, dass der Begriff "gerade Zahl" älter ist, als der Begriff "negative Zahl", aber das hindert ja nicht daran, ihn analog zu erweitern.

Comment: @feeela: in Niederländisch ist das `even` und `oneven` oder in Französisch `pair` und `impair`.

Comment: @jonathan: habe nie Mathe sondern Zahnheilkunde studiert, aber kenne auch 0 und -4 als gerade und -1 und -7 als ungerade.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Eine mögliche Erklärung findet sich auf [dieser Seite des SWR](http://www.swr.de/blog/1000antworten/antwort/5138/warum-heisen-zahlen-die-durch-2-teilbar-sind-%E2%80%9Egerade-zahlen%E2%80%9C/):

> Die „geraden“ Zahlen lassen sich zurückführen auf das gotische Wort
>   „rathjo“, was einfach „Zahl“ bedeutete, und daraus wurde dann ein Verb
>   (ge-)rathjan – zählen. Daraus hat sich im Althochdeutschen „girat“
>   gebildet, was erst mal so viel hieß wie zählbar, gleichzählig.
>
> Warum sich die Wortbedeutung dann später reduziert hat auf „gerade“ im
>   Sinne von „in zwei gleiche Hälften teilbar“, das weiß offenbar niemand
>   so richtig. Eine Möglichkeit könnte sein: Die Vorsilbe ge- in den
>   germanischen Sprachen bedeutet (ähnlich wie co- oder com- im
>   Lateinischen) immer, dass etwas miteinander verbunden wird (bestes
>   Beispiel: gem-einsam). Rathjan war „zählen“, ge-rathjan könnte dann
>   die sinngemäße Bedeutung bekommen haben „paarweise zählen“, woraus
>   sich dann girat „paarweise zählbar“ entwickelt hat.

Comment: Bessere Quelle: [DWDS – gerade](https://www.dwds.de/wb/gerade#etymwb).

Answer (score 12):

So als Mathematiker habe ich auch noch eine Erklärung.

Wenn man ein Torte in eine gerade Anzahl von Stücken schneiden will, dann kann man in gerader Linie durch die Mitte schneiden, während das bei einer ungeraden Anzahl nicht geht.

Ist doch plausible, ob historisch zutreffend kann ich genauso wie bei den anderen Spekulationen nicht sagen.

Comment: +1 Halte ich zwar nicht für eine wahrscheinliche Erklärung, aber sie gefällt mir trotzdem außerordentlich gut. Demnächst nenne ich die ungeraden Zahlen "winklig" mit Hinweis darauf, dass man nur mit derartigen Schnitten einen Kuchen in eine ungerade Anzahl Stücke aufteilen kann :)

Comment: Ich bin mir ziemlich sicher, dass der Begriff gerade Zahl in der Vergangenheit zum Teil in dieser Form in der Schule gelehrt wurde, aber dass sagt nur wenig über die Herkunft des Begriffes aus.

Comment: Da das eine absolute Spekulation ist und mit an Sicherheit grenzender Wahrscheinlichkeit eine falsche Spekulation, gebe ich hier -1.

Comment: Aber nur, wenn alle Stücke gleich groß sind. Ich weiß ja nicht, wie das bei euch ist, aber bei Familienfesten in meiner Verwandtschaft wird das Verteilen von Tortenstücken immer von vielen "Bitte ein kleines!"- und einzelnen "Bitte ein großes!"-Rufen begleitet.

Answer (score 4):

Meine Vermutung ist recht simpel:

*Gerade* ist/war ein anderer Ausdruck für *gleich* (siehe die [Wortherkunft](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/gerade_linear_aufrecht)). Ähnlich verhält es sich mit der englischen Übersetzung *even* (die auch gleich, glatt, gerade, ... bedeutet).

Diese Zahlen lassen sich also in zwei gleiche Teile teilen. "Zwei gerade Teile" sagt heute niemand mehr, aber durchaus möglich, daß es früher üblich war. Irgendwann wurde dann *gerade* nicht mehr für *gleich* verwendet, außer eben bei Zahlen.

**Ergänzung:**
Vielleicht liegt der Ursprung für die Verwendung von *gerade* und *gleich* als Synonyme in der Balkenwaage. Wenn auf beiden Seiten das Gewicht gleich groß ist, ist der Balken gerade (horizontal).

Comment: Da das nur eine Spekulation ist, gebe ich hier -1

Answer (score 1):

Duden Herkunftswörterbuch:
**gerade** durch zwei ohne Rest teilbar: Die Adjektivbildung mhd. gerat, ahd. girat gleichzählend, gerade (von Zahlen) gehört zu der germ. Wortgruppe von got. raÞjo Zahl, ga-raÞjan zählen (vgl. Rede). Im heutigen Sprachgefühl wird 1gerade als mit 2gerade identisch empfunden.

Answer (score -1):

Ich rate nur: Eine gerade Zahl von Dingen, zum Beispiel Bücher, lässt sich auf zwei gleich hohe Stapel aufteilen, das heißt die obere Kante der Stapel ist gerade. Wenn man 7 Bücher aufteilt in 3 Bücher und 4 Bücher, und die Stapel nebeneinander stellt, ist die obere Kante ungerade.

Comment: Klingt eher nach Volksethymologie, ist aber durchaus plausibel.

Comment: Wäre nur plausibel, wenn man etwas nimmt, was häufiger gleichdick/-hoch/-breit ist als Bücher.

Comment: Da das nur eine Spekulation ist, und sehr wahrscheinlich falsch, gebe ich hier -1.